# How to get the start and end position of the selected portion from the webview in android

Tags: android, webview, textselection

In web view i found default selection on long press.but after selection we have to click on the selected portion to copy to clipboard. i want to copy the selected portion to clipboard  when a button presses.how can i make it possible please help me...

Answer (score 4):

You can execute method javascript of webview:

Method javascript to get element id, start position and end position

```
 function(){
 var html = ""; 
 if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
  var sel = window.getSelection(); 
 } 
 return      sel.anchorNode.parentElement.id+':'+sel.anchorOffset+':'+sel.focusOffset; 
 })();
```

executing on webview:

```
webview.evaluateJavascript(script, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        selectedData = s; //value of javascript return
        selectedData = selectedData.replaceAll("\"", "");
        String array[] = new String[3];
        elementId = array[0];
        startPosition=array[1];
        endPosition=array[2];
        Log.d("WebView runtime", selectedText); 
    }
});
```

if you want get text of selection use this:

```
 function(){
 var html = ""; 
 if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
  var sel = window.getSelection(); 
 } 
 return sel.text; 
 })();
```

to execute calling of this method you can create a custom callback

```
private class TesteCallback implements Callback {

    private MyWebView mywebview;

    private TextMark textmark;

    public TesteCallback(MyWebView mywebview) {
        this.mywebview = mywebview;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        mode.setTitle("Chose color");

        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pagina2, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * create custom itens, remove useless itens
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
        // Remove the "cut" option
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut);
        // Remove the "copy all" option
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.copy);

        return true;
    }
@Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        mywebview.pegarSelecao();

        textmark = new TextMark();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.red:
            // do some stuff

            break;
        case R.id.yellow:
            // do some stuff

            break;
        case R.id.blue:
            // do some stuff

            break;
        default:

            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}//end class
```

if you need use a custom callback you need create a custom webview and calling callback:

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {
public MyWebView(Context context) {

    super(context);
    this.contexto = context;

}
public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

///////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
    ViewParent parent = getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        return null;
    }

    mActionModeCallback = new TesteCallback(this); //this line call custom callback
    return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
}

}
```